# Send zabbix alerts with HTML template

Tags: zabbix

I would like to send zabbix alerts in a good format instead of the default one. 
I haven't installed zabbix from sources so I can't modify the file `src/libs/zbxemail/email.c.` to change `plaintext` with `html`. 
Is there another way to do that please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way, I'm afraid (or that I know of). However, you can use an external call / new media type to send mails, via PHPmailer or python or even a shell-script, using whatever message body you like - even HTML. It's not *really* nice, but it works. I've done it myself, but not recently, check [this howto](https://blog.keios.eu/note/html-e-mails-zabbix).

Main info:

Create script in `/etc/zabbix/alert.d/`, e.g. `zabbix_html_mail.sh`.

Edit the script, enter the following (or similar):

```
#!/bin/sh
export smtpemailfrom=zabbix@example.org
export zabbixemailto="$1"
export zabbixsubject="$2"
export zabbixbody="$3"
export smtpserver=SMTP_HOST
export smtplogin=SMTP_LOGIN
export smtppass=SMTP_PASSWORD

/usr/bin/sendEmail -f $smtpemailfrom -t $zabbixemailto -u $zabbixsubject \
-m $zabbixbody -s $smtpserver:25 -xu $smtplogin -xp $smtppass -o tls=no \
-o message-content-type=html
```

Create new media type in zabbix, using `script` as `type`, enter path of your script, then enter your message in HTML format, using `{TRIGGER.STATUS}`, `{TRIGGER.URL}`, `{TRIGGER.XXXXXXX}` in your message body / subject and so on.